# Unity экземпляры класса и ссылки на объекты

Tags: c#, unity3d

Возник один вопрос по игровому движку Unity.
Допустим я хочу создать экземпляр класса Camera.

`Camera cam = New Camera();`

Но в некоторых справках и уроках люди просто пишут:

`Camera cam;`

Поиск по интернету вывел меня на официальную документацию, где написано:

> you can create an object reference without creating an object at all:
>   Customer object2;

То есть получается, что во втором случае я создаю ссылку на объект Camera, а не экземпляр класса. Если рассуждение верно, то  я могу создать две ссылки на один объект, допустим:

```
Camera Testcam1;
Camera Testcam2;
```

И если я присвою одной ссылке значение, то вторая тоже должна изменится так, как они ссылаются на один объект. Но этого не происходит.

```
Testcam1 = Camera.main;
Debug.Log(Testcam2);
Debug.Log(Testcam1);
```

В консоль выводится сообщение что Testcam2 имеет Null, а Testcam1 получает значение камеры. Возможно, я тоже должен что-то присвоить второй ссылке, прежде чем у неё появится значение. Но в любом случае, прошу помощи разъяснить мне, является такая вещь как `Camera Testcam1;` - ссылкой на объект, либо чем то еще.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы абсолютно верно рассуждаете до этого момента

> И если я присвою одной ссылке значение, то вторая тоже должна изменится так, как они ссылаются на один объект. Но этого не происходит.

Рассмотрим ситуацию

```
Camera Testcam1;
Camera Testcam2;
```

в данный момент обе ссылки пустые - null.

Если мы присвоем одной пустой ссылке, другую пустую ссылку и после этого изменим значений в одной из них:

```
Testcam1 = Testcam2;
Testcam2 = camera.Main;
 //Testcam1 будет  nul
 //Testcam2 будет camera.Main
```

Testcam1  указывает на экземпляр класса, а Testcam2 продолжает быть пустой.
Это связано с тем что хоть они оба и были null, это не было ссылкой на общий объект.

**НО**

Если после этого повторим:

```
 Testcam1 = Testcam2;
   //Testcam1 будет camera.Main
   //Testcam2 будет тот же объект что и Testcam2
```

Answer (score 2):

Объявление вида

```
Тип имя_переменной;
```

создает нулевую ссылку для ссылочных типов (классов) или переменную со значением по умолчанию для типов значений (структур), если является полем класса, иначе - неинициализированное значение.